# How to handle a null returned from a method?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

I have a graph related method which returns the neighboring nodes of a certain node.
If the one node has no neighbors it returns null, the method is the following

```java
public Iterable<Node> getNeighbors(Node v) {
    if (!this.adjacencyList.get(v).isEmpty())
        return this.adjacencyList.get(v);
    return null;
}
```

I try to avoid the exception using the following :

```java
if (graph.getNeighbors(nodeIterator.name) == null)
            nodeIterator = all_graph_nodes.iterator().next();
Iterable<Node> adjNodes = graph.getNeighbors(nodeIterator.name);
```

The `NullPointerException` is raised even using the previous code.
How to solve this ?

Comment: Please provide the NullPointerException stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still getting an NPE, then the problem is in `getNeighbours` and not the second snippet.

1. `this.adjacencyList` is null, -OR-
2. `this.adjacencyList.get(v)` returns null.

Given that you're passing a **name** to a method that will then do a lookup by **node**, and that you can't call `.get(someNodeRef)` on a list, `adjacencyList` is probably some sort of hashmap, so your names are off and you should rename some things. Map's `.get(x)` method returns `null` if an entry is not found, so most likely the culprit is that `v` isn't in the map at all, and thus `.get(v).isEmpty()` throws NPE.

The fixes are as follows:

1. You should *NEVER* return null when a valid sentinel value that carries the intended semantic meaning is available. A mouthful, but it means here: Why are you returning null when you intend to treat that the exact same way as 'zero nodes'? There is an instance of `Iterable<Node>` that properly represents the concept of zero nodes, and it isn't `null`. It's `List.of()` or equivalent: An empty list has no nodes. Great. That's what you intended. So return that.
2. `.get(v).isEmpty()` is bad code here, as it would mean an NPE occurs if you ask for a non-existent node. Unless, of course, you *want* it to work that way. An easy way out is the defaulting mechanism: Call `.getOrDefault` instead:

```
if (!this.adjacencyList.getOrDefault(v, List.of()).isEmpty()) ....
```

except, of course, you should never be returning null when you can return an empty list instead, so your getNeighbours method becomes simply:

```
return adjacencyMap.getOrDefault(v, List.of());
```

that one-liner will fix all things.

In general, if you are writing code where `null` is dealt with in some way, and some sentinel value (such as a blank string or an empty list) is dealt with in the same way, your code is badly styled; however you got that `null` should have gotten you that empty value instead. e.g. if you ever write this:

```
if (x == null || x.isEmpty()) ...
```

you messed up. Figure out where you got x from. Update it there, make x the blank sentinel (`""` for strings, `List.of` for lists, etcetera).

That, and use `.getOrDefault` and other such methods more: Methods that let you provide what should happen when e.g. a key is not found.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably avoid returning null from your getNeighbors method. It's not good practice to return null for Iterables, Iterators and Collections, since an empty iterable would represent the same concept (there is nothing in that adjacency list) without all the dangers of null. And your code would be simpler. You can check if the iterable contains anything and if not then default to the full iterator.

Comment: I tried returning an empty set, but same error

Comment: Then please provide the exception stack trace

Comment: The stack has no lines just mentioning the exception nothing more to disclose that you should know except that the error occurs at the if statement, but your logic doesn't work, it is wrong and yields the same error in my code sorry

Comment: Well, the error will always tell you what line is erroring, etc. Telling people who try to help you they're wrong without giving them the information they ask for is not going to get you much help. Please provide the code that's not returning null and show us on which line you get the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid returning `null` at all cost. This is of high danger as it may cause Null Pointer Exceptions to be thrown during runtime. Such exceptions are horrific to debug as they usually hide implementation errors due to the place where the exception was thrown is most likely far away from the original implementation error.
Your case is actually a good example of such behavior as it is not directly understandable where the NPE is coming from.

In situations in which the appearance of a `null` value is inevitable (e.g. as @rzwitserloot pointed out, Java's [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) `get` method) and there is the possibility of exposing it to client objects (e.g. your `getNeighbors` method may expose such `null` value) I like to use Java's [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) which (as stated in the docs) is:

> A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value. If a value is present, isPresent() will return true and get() will return the value.

This object will act as wrapper to objects which may be assigned as `null` thus preventing it to be used directly and *possibly* preventing NPEs to be thrown.

In your case this would apply as follows (note that this is assuming that `adjancencyList` is a non-null object and that its `get` method is the one actually throwing the NPE):

```
public Optional<Iterable<Node>> getNeighbors(Node v) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(this.adjacencyList.get(v));
}
```

```
if (!graph.getNeighbors(nodeIterator.name).isPresent()) {
    nodeIterator = all_graph_nodes.iterator().next();
}

Iterable<Node> adjNodes = graph.getNeighbors(nodeIterator.name).get();
```

Note that by wrapping the original `get` method in an `Optional` object there is no longer the propagation of a raw `null` value hence preventing it to be used by the client. You are moving the responsibility of dealing with `null` to your side only and protecting clients to handle them instead.

Another great advantage of using `Optional` as a method's return type is that it implicitly declares that the return object of the method may or may not be present. This forces clients to understand that its return value may be empty (`null`) and thus force it to act accordingly.

Comment: thx but this line `Iterable<Node> adjNodes = graph.getNeighbors(nodeIterator.name);
` doesn't work given that getNeighbors returns Optional

Comment: you meant to use ifPresent() ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the `get()` method of `Optional` which retrieves the actual wrapped object: `Iterable<Node> adjNodes = graph.getNeighbors(nodeIterator.name).get();`

Comment: doesn't work either it provides an object not an iterable as the IDE says

Comment: Could you provide more details about why it doesn't work? I just tested it locally and it is working.

Comment: IDE states that :
`Required type :Iterable
<Node.Node>
Provided:
Object`

Comment: I am not aware of why such error is being thrown. It is strange as this implementation is pretty straightforward:

1. Change the return type of the `getNeightbords` method to wrap it inside an `Optional`
2. Change the return statement of `getMethods` to return an optional instead (`return Optional.ofNullable(this.adjacencyList.get(v))`)
3. Update the call to `getMethods` to call `get` method of the `Optional` to retrieve its wrapped value (after making sure it is present)

That should be it...